# Circleci tests passing but then sitting there until timing out

Tags: circleci

I'm running Jasmine tests which are passing, but then nothing happens until eventual timeout. What am I missing?

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 49 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.539 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 50 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.542 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 51 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.546 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 52 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.549 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 53 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.553 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 54 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.562 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 55 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.567 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 56 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.573 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 57 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.575 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 58 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.583 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 59 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.588 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 60 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.593 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 61 of 61 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.621 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 61 of 61 SUCCESS (0.446 secs / 0.621 secs)

command ((npm :test)) took more than 10 minutes since last output
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Support solved the issue:

> node_modules/karma/bin/karma start --log-level=debug --single-run
>   Running single-run causes phantomJS to shut down cleanly. This is apparently a special "Continuous Integration" mode for Karma. http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html
>
> So, all you should have to do is add
>
> singleRun: true, to your karma.conf.js file.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: true,
```

Set *singleRun* to true in your karma config file. This would return 1 or 0 depending on if the test passed or failed when it ended as opposed to watching for changes infinitely in the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for running tests is to be in watch mode in the karma.config.

If you like to run ng test in a single-run manner please execute this command:

`ng test --watch false`